# create nested attributes with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models **Restocking**, **Product**, and **Size**

```
#Product
  has_many :sizes, as: :sizeable 

#Size
  belongs_to :sizeable, polymorphic: true
```

restocking.rb

```
class Restocking < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sizes, as: :sizeable
  belongs_to :product
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sizes


  def update_existing_product
    product = self.product
    product.update_attributes(
     price: self.price,
     buying_price: self.buying_price,
    )
    sizes = Size.where(sizeable_id: self.product_id)
    self.sizes.each do |restocking_size|
        sizes.each do |product_size|
          if product_size.size_name == restocking_size.size_name
            product_size.quantity += restocking_size.quantity
            product_size.save
         end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

So the method `update_existing_product`update prices and quantity of existing sizes...

If a similar `size_name` is found it updates the existing size quantity otherwise it creates a new one...
I don't manage to correctly create new sizes...

I am supposed to use this `Size.create` method, but when I put it on the loop it creates the same size many times.

```
Size.create!(
    sizeable_id: self.product_id,
    sizeable_type: "Product",
    size_name: restocking_size.size_name,
    quantity: restocking_size.quantity,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Size` is created many times because of how your loop is constructed.

Fix for your code can look like this:

```
self.sizes.each do |restocking_size|
  if (existing_size = sizes.find{|s| s.size_name == restocking_size.size_name })
    existing_size.tap{|s| s.quantity += restocking_size.quantity }.save!
  else
    # no existing, here goes create
  end
end
```

But keep in mind, that handling this at application level can lead to race conditions, if this code happens to run at the same time when some other code updates same data.
For example:

1. we have 10 items of size A of item B
2. restoking another 5
3. code runs, fetches `sizes`, there we have 10 in `quantity`
4. at this moment someone buys one item of that size, 9 items left and is this written to db
5. restocking continues to run - adds 5 to 10, writes 15 to db
6. `quantity` is 15, while one item has been sold

Can be avoided by using `record#with_lock{ here update happens }` in every place where you update counter (but this reloads the record, can be inefficient for large volumes).

Comment: Thank you when I add the `Size.create` it re recreates the existing sizes... How can I avoid this?

Comment: @johan see code example in answer, it should not (you can add logging to see if it really finds existing one)

Comment: I used your code plus my `Size.create` inside the `else` it recreate the updated sizes

Comment: Then first bet is that it does not find existing sizes, check if `sizes.find{...}` returns the record

Comment: Thanks for pointing `record#with_lock{ here update happens }`i will check this out :)